# After root changes table name, root gets error when trying to revoke permissions from end user on a non existent table name

Tags: mysql, validation, permissions, passwords

I am currently using the `root` account

I have a table - `user1_db.table1` and `user1` has the following permissions -

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR user1@localhost;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, INDEX, ALTER ON `user1_db`.`table1` TO `user1`@`localhost`
```

Now, I rename `table1` to `table2` but I forgot to revoke the permissions from `user1` on `table1` first

I now grant the same permissions on `table2` to `user1`

Now I have the permissions as -

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR user1@localhost;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, INDEX, ALTER ON `user1_db`.`table1` TO `user1`@`localhost`
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, INDEX, ALTER ON `user1_db`.`table2` TO `user1`@`localhost`
```

So now there is permissions granted on a non-existent table name - `table1`

I try to revoke the permission.

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON `user1_db`.`table1` FROM `user1`;
```

But, I get the error -

```
ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements
```

I tried the following to decrease password complexity requirement -

```
SET GLOBAL VALIDATE_PASSWORD.POLICY = LOW;
SET GLOBAL VALIDATE_PASSWORD.LENGTH = 2;
SET GLOBAL VALIDATE_PASSWORD.MIXED_CASE_COUNT = 0;
SET GLOBAL VALIDATE_PASSWORD.NUMBER_COUNT = 0;
SET GLOBAL VALIDATE_PASSWORD.SPECIAL_CHAR_COUNT = 0;
```

But still the problem persists. So how can I revoke permissions from `user1` on a non-existent table - `table1`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this workaround.

From root account I create a table `user1_db.table1`

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (col1 INT);
```

Then I logged out, restarted mysql server and again logged in.

Now the query -

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON `user1_db`.`table1` FROM `user1`;
```

runs without any error.

Now, `user1` permissions are -

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR user1@localhost;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, INDEX, ALTER ON `user1_db`.`table2` TO `user1`@`localhost`
```

Then I deleted table `table1`

```
DROP TABLE user1_db.table1;
```